# Changing jQuery functions show and hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry for the dummy question, but I can't find solution by my own beacause I'm only on the start of learning JS.

I have 2 function which work well, but I need to make some changes. 
What should I do to make this:

When I select radiobutton "Text 1", or it on hover - all pics are shown and they don't disappear when another radiobuttons on hover.

When I select radiobutton "Text 2" or "Text 3" - it works the same as now - only one picture is shown, and other are shown on hover.

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/832068/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.desc').hover(
    function() {
      var $pic = $('#' + $(this).data('picid'));
      console.log($(this).children('input'))
      if (!$(this).children('input').prop('checked')) {
        $pic.show();
        $('#pic1').css('opacity', '0.4');
      }
    },
    function() {
      var $pic = $('#' + $(this).data('picid'));
      if (!$(this).children('input').prop('checked')) {
        $pic.hide();
        $('#pic1').css('opacity', '1.0');
      }
    }
  );


  $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    $('.hide, .img').hide();
    var $pic = $('#' + $(this).data('picid'));
    var $text = $('#' + $(this).data('textid'));

    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $pic.show();
      $text.show();
      $('#pic1').css('opacity', '0.4');
    } else {
      $pic.hide();
      $text.hide();
      $('#pic1').css('opacity', '1.0');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <form class="radiobuttons">
    <p class="desc" data-picid="pic1"><input class="packageBtn" type="radio" name="item1" value="1" data-picid="pic1" data-textid="text1">Text 1</p>
    <p class="desc" data-picid="pic2"><input class="packageBtn" type="radio" name="item1" value="2" data-picid="pic2" data-textid="text2">Text 2</p>
    <p class="desc" data-picid="pic3"><input class="packageBtn" type="radio" name="item1" value="3" data-picid="pic3" data-textid="text3">Text 3</p>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <div class="img" id="pic1" style='display:none'><img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/facebook-messenger-logo-image-22.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="img" id="pic2" style='display:none'><img src="http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/1012/QettoIcons/w256h2561350658940jpg.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="img" id="pic3" style='display:none'><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/star/star_PNG1594.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your question the code will be like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $text_1_checked=false;

        $('.desc').hover(
            function() {
                    if($text_1_checked){
                    return;
                }
                var $pic = $('#' + $(this).data('picid'));
                console.log($(this).children('input'))
                if (!$(this).children('input').prop('checked')) {
                    $pic.show();
                    $('#pic1').css('opacity', '0.4');
                }
            },
            function() {
                    if($text_1_checked){
                    return;
                }
                var $pic = $('#' + $(this).data('picid'));
                if (!$(this).children('input').prop('checked')) {
                    $pic.hide();
                    $('#pic1').css('opacity', '1.0');
                }
            }
        );


        $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
            $('.hide, .img').hide();
            var $pic = $('#' + $(this).data('picid'));
            var $text = $('#' + $(this).data('textid'));
            if ($(this).prop('checked')&&$(this).prop('value')=="1") {
                $('.img').show();
                $text_1_checked=true;
                $('#pic1').css('opacity', '1.0');
                return ;



            }else{

             $text_1_checked=false;


            }
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                $pic.show();
                $text.show();
                $('#pic1').css('opacity', '0.4');
            }

            else {
                $pic.hide();
                $text.hide();
                $('#pic1').css('opacity', '1.0');
            }
        });

    });
```

i add a flag to know if the first radio is checked or not

Comment: @MohammadShrateh Thank you! It works! Is it possible to make that if "Text 1" - on hover - all pics are shown too, like if "Text 1" selected?

Comment: Yes you just need to add the if else statement like in change event and delete the first condition

Answer (score 0):

please try below code if it solves your purpose

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
            var temp = $(this).val();                
                $('img').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).attr('caption').toLocaleLowerCase() == 
                temp.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
                        $(this).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                });                
        });

    });

<body>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="Text 1" />Text1
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="Text 2" />Text2
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="Text 3" />Text3
<img src="text1.PNG" caption="Text 1" style="display:none"/><img src="text2.PNG"  caption="Text 2" style="display:none"/><img src="text3.PNG"  caption="Text 3" style="display:none"/>
```